# Memory leak in Delphi 'diamond.style' for FireMonkey in Win32. Am I using it correctly?

Tags: delphi, styles, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I've applied the 'diamond.style' from the [FireMonkey Premium Styles Pack for RAD Studio XE7](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29928) and get a memory leak on closing my app. I am wondering if I am using TStyleBook correctly, although various other styles work fine. This is what I'm doing with a very simple test in XE7 that shows the problem.

1. Use File | New | Multi-device application (then choose blank application for simplicity).
2. Set the target platform to Win32.
3. Drop a TStyleBook on the form and edit the Form's 'stylebook' property to point to this.
4. To the project source, add:   ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := true;
5. Run the project, it should open and close fine.
6. Double-click the style book. Click 'load' and nominate the style file  "C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\15.0\Styles\Diamond.style".
7. Click 'Apply and close'
8. Run the project again. You see the style applied to form and border etc.
9. When you close it you see a memory leak.

[image]

I've played around trying to dispose the stylebook on shutdown etc. but to no avail. Am I using TStyleBook correctly?

Comment: @Uwe: So I am using it correctly! Thanks!.